# Best way to get next element of a List in Elm

Tags: elm

I am currently trying to figure out the best way of traversing a List.
What do I mean by traversing?

**Example:**

I have a List of Users:

```
userList : List User 
userList =
    [user, user, user, user]
```

and I have a currentUser, which must be a user out of the userList

So what I want to achieve is: 
I want to have something like *List.getNext* which takes the userList and the current user and returns the next user in the list, relative to the currentUser

Here is my implementation. I think it is very complicated - so has anyone an idea how to do this in a better style?

```
traverseList : List a -> a -> Maybe (Maybe a)
traverseList list currentElement =
    let
        indexList =
            List.indexedMap
                (\index element ->
                    if element == currentElement then
                        index
                    else
                        -1
                )
                list

        currentAsIndex =
            let
                mayBeIndex =
                    List.maximum indexList
            in
                case mayBeIndex of
                    Just index ->
                        index

                    Nothing ->
                        0

        getWanted =
            List.map
                (\( id, element ) ->
                    if id == (currentAsIndex + 1) then
                        Just element
                    else
                        Nothing
                )
                (List.indexedMap (,) list)
                |> List.filter
                    (\element ->
                        element /= Nothing
                    )
                |> List.head

    in
        getWanted
```

**Explanation:**

My approach is to get the list, make an index list of the given list (looks like this [-1, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1])

Then I get the maximum of this list - as this gives me the position of the current user in a List.indexedMap.

Then I iterate the original as an List.indexedMap and figure out the next one (in our case No. 4) and return that element. Else I return nothing.

Then I filter this List of Nothings and just one user and extract the user from the list by using List.head.

The Result is a Maybe (Maybe user)... that is not so nice... or?

Thanks for any ideas to do something like this in a better functional way.

I really try to get better in functional programming..

Comment: What should be returned if the current user is the last one in the list? Nothing, or the first of the list?

Comment: Currently in this implementation it returns the first. For my usecase this is ok. => Should return the first element ... haha.. but I am wondering why it returns the first .. :) I dont know...

Comment: Ah ok... now I got it. Because the maximum of a list of -1 is -1. Later I just get the head... so it returns the first element... Ok. that is good but was not intented ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pretty naive, recursive solution:

```
getWanted  : List a -> a -> Maybe a
getWanted list currentElement = 
    let findNextInList l = case l of
        []             -> Nothing
        x :: []        -> if x == currentElement
                          then List.head list
                          else Nothing
        x :: y :: rest -> if x == currentElement
                          then Just y
                          else findNextInList (y :: rest)
    in
        findNextInList list
```

The idea here is look at the first two elements of the list, and if the first is the current element, take the second. If not, try again with the tail of the list.

Corner cases must be handled (you can write at least 4 unit tests for this function):

- current element not found at all
- current element is the last in the list
- the list might be empty

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but recursion is a pretty common technique in functional programming, so I wanted to share this approach.

Comment: i like that approach :)

Comment: @marschro thanks, but I admit it is not very concise. There are five cases/ifs in my code and it is hard to follow them all at a glance. I do not like it myself, and I already suspected I am missing something. farmio has a much better approach. Explicit recursion is still useful sometimes, but in general it is preferred to use higher-order functions and composition. So I hope you learned something about recursion and take this answer more as an educational one.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I took it as a learning example. I totally understood recursion and list destructuring with that 

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to import [list-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest) you can use

```
import List.Extra as LE exposing ((!!))

getNext : a -> List a -> Maybe a
getNext item list =
    list
        |> LE.elemIndex item
        |> Maybe.map ((+) 1)
        |> Maybe.andThen ((!!) list)
```

If the found element is the last in the list it returns `Nothing`

Comment: This is short and very nice. Thank you for that idea. I cannot mark multiple solution so I prefer the idea of @stholzm that gives me a good base of understanding how to handle such things. Thanks!

Comment: So elegant! I think you can simply add "modulo list length" to make it work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
getNext : List a -> a -> Maybe a
getNext list element =
  list 
    |> List.drop 1 
    |> zip list
    |> List.filter (\(current, next) -> current == element)
    |> List.map (\(current, next) -> next)
    |> List.head

zip : List a -> List b -> List (a,b)
zip = List.map2 (,)
```

We drop the first element of the list and then zip it with the original list to get a list of tuples. Each element of the tuple contains the current element and the next element. We then filter that list, take the 'next' element from the tuple and take the head of the final list.

Answer (score 1):

I like farmio's library-based approach best, and is what I'll be using in future.

That said, for being new to elm and not looking over its libraries, my erstwhile approach has been as in the following: i.e. index the list, find index if any of searched-for item, get item at next index if any.

```
nextUser : List User -> User -> Maybe User
nextUser lst usr =
    let
        numberedUsers =
            List.map2 (\idx u -> ( idx, u )) (List.range 1 (List.length lst)) lst

        usrIdx =
            List.filter (\( idx, u ) -> u.name == usr.name) numberedUsers
                |> List.head
                |> Maybe.map Tuple.first
                |> Maybe.withDefault -1
    in
        List.filter (\( idx, u ) -> idx == usrIdx + 1) numberedUsers
            |> List.head
            |> Maybe.map Tuple.second
```

Another way with as much fiddlery would be to use folds.

Maybe instead of `List` just use `Array`, which provides index-based access.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers to the concrete question. I'd like to suggest an alternative model, since this approach has some downsides:

- You rely on checking equality of users. This limits the user type, e.g., there can't be functions in there.
- Looking up a user in a list that doesn't guarantee that all users are different is fragile: If the list happens to end up as `[user1, user2, user1, user3]`, the rotation will never reach `user3`.
- Nothing guarantees that the current user is in the list, hence the `Maybe` in the return type of the other answers which is hard to deal with correctly.

Thus, let's assume your current model is

```
type alias Model =
    { currentUser : User
    , users : [User]
    }
```

and what you're asking for is

```
rotateUser : Model -> Model
rotateUser model =
  let
    nextUser = Maybe.withDefault
        model.currentUser
        (getNext model.users model.currentUser)
  in
    { model | currentUser = nextUser }

getNext : List a -> a -> Maybe a
...
```

How about instead of implementing `getNext`, we change the model to make life easier:

```
type alias Model =
    { currentUser : User
    , otherUsers : [User]
    }

rotateUser : Model -> Model
rotateUser model =
    case model.otherUsers of
        [] -> model
        (nextUser::rest) ->
            { model
            | currentUser = nextUser
            , otherUsers = rest ++ [model.currentUser]
            }
```